# Error with an If Statement within a GUI (Always falls into ELSE never IF)

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement, jframe

I'm making a really basic Login prompt GUI for revision for my Java exam next week (this exercise could possibly come up in the exam so that's why I'm trying to ace it first). Basically when you type in a certain name, in this case 'joe' it'll say verified, otherwise it'll say unverified. However, even when I type in joe it'll still say unverified. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong? Thanks.

```
package gui.eventHandler;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class EventHandlerExample2_NameConfirmation {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JButton button1;
private JLabel label;
private JTextField fname;

public EventHandlerExample2_NameConfirmation() {

    frame = new JFrame("Log In");
    panel = new JPanel();
    label = new JLabel("First Name: ");
    fname = new JTextField(20);

    // Actions for when the OK button is clicked
    // Implementing the ActionListener as an anonymous inner class
    button1 = new JButton("Submit");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String inputname = fname.getText();

            if (inputname == "joe") {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Verified user " + inputname);
            } else {
                //selects this option regardless of entry
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid user " + inputname);
            }

        }
    });

    panel.add(label); // add the label
    panel.add(fname); // textField
    panel.add(button1); // and button to the panel

    frame.add(panel); // add panel onto the frame
    frame.setVisible(true); // By default its invisible
    frame.setSize(600, 70); // 600 width 70 height
    frame.setLocation(350, 350); // roughly center screen
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // exit when closed

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventHandlerExample2_NameConfirmation app = new EventHandlerExample2_NameConfirmation();
}

}
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks for linking this, all I needed to do was change == to .equals

Comment: Yup, make sure to read the answers on that question, there's alot of good important information there.

Comment: Now I know! Will keep reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string.equals to compare strings the operator == checks if the references to the string are equal

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, somebody linked me a similar post a few minutes ago and said the same thing. Now I know!